# Laravel force HTTPS with .htaccess too many redirects using Amazon ELB

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

Pulling my hair out. I need to force to HTTPS and getting too many redirects with the below in .htaccess file. Based on my research on Stack, this should work. Cleared cache, cookies, all that.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 11):

Ok, figured it out. Because I'm behind a load balancer, I had to replace:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

WITH:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

More info on why you need that header here: [Load Balancers and HTTPS](https://www.tobymackenzie.com/blog/2015/04/22/load-balancers-and-https/)

Comment: works for me in AWS ec2 Linux 2 with Laravel .htaccess. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (with Codeigniter and using AWS Classic ELB) but the above solution did not work for me. I had to apply the rewrite conditions and rules in the https.conf file and then restart the apache server. See here for how to do it. Also worth noting that AWS don't recommend the .htaccess approach (not sure why):

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvqZV_50GlQ

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem with Laravel 6 on a shared hosting. When I configured CPanel to redirect my app to a secure `https` url, it kept redirecting infinitely.

I had this in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^biblioteca\.vallenateca\.com$ [OR]   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.biblioteca\.vallenateca\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/biblioteca\.vallenateca\.com" [R=301,L]
```

I added this two lines.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^biblioteca\.vallenateca\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.biblioteca\.vallenateca\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/biblioteca\.vallenateca\.com" [R=301,L]
```

And it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8, the default on the .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

This worked for me and I'm using Inmotion hosting:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```